# ngrx chain action after clearing the store in metareducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

In my application inside the metareducer, i'm clearing the store after a particular action is triggered. This action is just a navigation to the main page. The issue is I can't generate a new token inside the effect linked to this action because it is cleared by this function :

```
  return function (state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
    if (action.type === OfferActionTypes.GoToBaseInfoPage) {
      state = undefined;
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}
```

I tried to chain one action after the navigation in the related effect but it does not work:

```
  navigateToIndex$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromOfferAction.OfferActionTypes.GoToBaseInfoPage),
    tap (() => this._router.navigate(['', this.currentLang]) ),
    map(() => this._store.dispatch(new AuthenticationCustomTokenRequested()))
   );
```

Is there a way to launch the action to get a new token after the navigation and clearing are done ?

thank you

Comment: check recent actions in dev tools

Comment: the last action is actually to request a new token but it might be the way i wrote this effect. maybe, i don't know

Answer (score 0):

1- use effect to dispatch new action (for example NEW_ACTION) after logout and navigation

```
 @Effect()
  logout$ = this.actions.ofType(fromActions.LOGOUT).pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      fromPromise(this.service.signOut()).pipe(
        map(() => new NewAction()),
        catchError(err =>
          of(new AuthError(err)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

2- update your code from

```
    if (action.type === OfferActionTypes.GoToBaseInfoPage) {
```

to

```
    if (action.type === OfferActionTypes.NEW_ACTION) {
```